# MVC SelectList setting random value as 'selected'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I have a hard coded select list, pulling Value and Text from the db.
I have a specific item I want to set as the "default", so I order the list to specifically put it first in line ("Wip").  However, when the list is rendered in HTML, the order of the list is correct, but the selected value is the item with the smallest value, even though it is at the bottom of the list due to ordering descending.

**Model**:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BinOptionsList { get; set; }
```

**Data Access**:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PopulateBinList()
    {
        using (var db = new InventoryContext())
        {
            var data = db.StorageBin.OrderByDescending(s => s.BinCode == "Wip").ThenBy(s => s.BinCode).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s.BinCode,
                Value = s.BinId.ToString()
            }).ToList();

            return data;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
    model.BinOptionsList = dal.PopulateBinList()
```

**View**:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BinId, Model.BinOptionsList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The list renders in the View with "Wip" as the first selection, but the rendered "selected=selected" option is the item with id=0.

I know I can set the 'Selected' value in the Data Access method, but then I cant use this in an edit form that would already have a selected value.

Update - **Rendered HTML**:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Bin Code must be a number." data-val-required="The Bin Code field is required." id="BinId" name="BinId">
    <option value="582">WIP</option>
    <option value="595">0888</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">0919</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">1A1</option>
    <option value="3">1A10</option>
    <option value="4">1A11</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the value of model.BinId when calling Html.DropDownListFor? Can you give the html generated by Html.DropDownListFor?

Comment: @the_lotus - Not sure how to find the BinId value, but I assume it is"0".  I have added the rendered HTML.

Comment: I have been playing with the ordering, changed ThenBy() to ThenByDescending(), but no change, it still sets the item with Value="0" as selected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure BindId is equal to 0. If BindId is a simple Integer then it will always be equal to 0 by default. You'll need to set it to 582 yourself or set it as Integer? which would set the default as null.

Comment: @the_lotus That makes sense.  Ok thanks.

Comment: As long as you set the `BinId` prop value to the correct value, that will be selected when the select element is rendered. That should work in your Edit method as well.

Comment: Moving the selected item to the top of the list might confuse users, IMHO.

Comment: @the_lotus - Your suggestion worked so if you want to add an answer, Ill mark it.

Comment: @BattlFrog happy to hear you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure BindId is equal to 0. If BindId is a simple Integer then it will always be equal to 0 by default. You'll need to set it to 582 yourself or set it as Integer? which would set the default as null.

Answer (score 0):

So you may not prefer this answer but let me outline one quick thing. Your select list should not be of your model. The value selected from your select this should be part of your model. You are putting too much overhead into your model and it is having in impact on your view. Refactor it. Put your select list in your ViewBag for you to use in your view, stop passing it back and forth. This will keep your model compact and allow you to set your options properly.

Here is a simple example.

What would be your Data Access (just stubbing it out for example sake and yes setting it to static for example simplicity):

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PopulateBinList()
    {

        return new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem {
            Text = "WIP", Value = "582"
        }, new SelectListItem {
            Text = "0888", Value = "595"
        } , new SelectListItem {
            Text = "0", Value = "0919"
        }, new SelectListItem {
            Text = "1", Value = "1"
        }};

    }
```

Then your model (just adding the one property for example)

```
public class BinModel
{
    public string BinId { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //load up your select list into the view bag
        ViewBag.BinOptions = ViewHelper.PopulateBinList();
        //preset the value of your desired object
        var bm = new BinModel { BinId = "582" };
        return View(bm);

    }
```

The in your view you are going to bind to model property but use your temp list defined in the view bag to fill the options. Presetting your model's property will auto select which value is defaulted in the select list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BinId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BinOptions, null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

Please let me know if this does not make sense or needs to be expanded on.